# regex to pass space and one more char and remove rest of the special char

Tags: php, regex, string

Here is my regex to remove the special characters.

But I dont want to remove space and `@` from text.

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

Above code does not allow space and also dont have clue about how to allow @ to persist.

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern to not replace them then: `'/[^A-Za-z0-9 @\-]/'`
Still, make sure that cleaner is still clean enough.

Looks like you should read a small text about perl-compatible regular expressions.